# Magento 2: connect to existing DB

Tags: magento2, database, configuration, deployment

I have deployed Magento 2.1.2 CE and have setup the database to use with this instance.

```
# http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html#instgde-install-cli-magento
php ${DIR_MAGE}/bin/magento setup:install  \
--admin-firstname="${ADMIN_FIRSTNAME}" \
--admin-lastname="${ADMIN_LASTNAME}" \
--admin-email="${ADMIN_EMAIL}" \
--admin-user="${ADMIN_USER}" \
--admin-password="${ADMIN_PASSWORD}" \
--base-url="${BASE_URL}" \
--backend-frontname="${BACKEND_FRONTNAME}" \
--language="${LANGUAGE}" \
--currency="${CURRENCY}" \
--timezone="${TIMEZONE}" \
--use-rewrites="${USE_REWRITES}" \
--use-secure="${USE_SECURE}" \
--use-secure-admin="${USE_SECURE_ADMIN}" \
--admin-use-security-key="${ADMI_USE_SECURITY_KEY}" \
--session-save="${SESSION_SAVE}" \
--cleanup-database \
--db-host="${DB_HOST}" \
--db-name="${DB_NAME}" \
--db-user="${DB_USER}" \
--db-password="${MAGE_DBPASS}" \
```

I want to re-deploy Magento instance and I want to use the same DB. I tried to run this command after re-deployment:

```
php ${DIR_MAGE}/bin/magento setup:config:set  \
--backend-frontname="${BACKEND_FRONTNAME}" \
--key="${SECURE_KEY}" \
--session-save="${SESSION_SAVE}" \
--db-host="${DB_HOST}" \
--db-name="${DB_NAME}" \
--db-user="${DB_USER}" \
--db-password="${MAGE_DBPASS}" \
```

this message is displayed:

```
We saved default values for these options: db-host, db-engine, db-prefix, db-model, db-init-statements.
```

but when I go to the front of my site I see that setup mode is started:

[image: Magento 2 setup mode after re-deployment]

How can I re-deploy Magento 2 CE and re-connect to existing DB?

Answer (score 1):

If you have DB already, you can modify app/etc/env.php to connect the existing DB

Between line 16 and 29:

```
  'db' =>
  array (
    'table_prefix' => '${DB_PREFIX}',
    'connection' =>
    array (
      'default' =>
      array (
        'host' => '${DB_HOST}',
        'dbname' => '${DB_NAME}',
        'username' => '${DB_USER}',
        'password' => '${MAGE_DBPASS}',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: I have fresh empty Magento 2 instance after re-deployment, w/o `app/etc/env.php` & `app/etc/config.php` :(

Comment: Did the folder app/etc is set to 777?

Comment: Thanks, @py-yick, I found the solution - I need to use `setup:install` again w/o `--cleanup-database` option and with the same admin user parameters (first, last, email, username, password).

Comment: Good to see you solved your problems. Just wonder why `app/etc/env.php` is not included on the core file?

Comment: I suppose files `app/etc/env.php` and `app/etc/config.php` are generated by   `bin/magento` in `setup:install` time. I have deployed M2 using composer.

Answer (score 1):

To use an existing database open `app/etc/env.php` and update your database credential.

Then double check to make sure the 'install' array key exists.

```
... 
'install' => array (
     'date' => 'Mon, 28 Nov 2016 23:01:06 +0000',
 ),
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to reinstall by doing the following steps:-

`generated/*` folder. It is also important to remove the `app/etc/config.php` and `app/etc/env.php` to do a fresh install.